# Is there a to View or browse the table for a row which a single or more values greater/less than a certain value

Tags: r

In stata is something like this
lets say i have the following table

```
**names sex     age**
Paul  Male    15
Peter Female  20
Mary  Female  12
Eve   Female  14
John  Male    10
```

stata command:

```
browse if age>12 & age<20
```

will return the table with

```
names sex     age
Paul  Male    15
Eve   Female  14
```

Kindly help me with an equivalent way to do this in R

I used the following command but it also returns missing value

```
View(starwars[starwars$mass > 100,])
```

In stata if add the `!=`. missing values are not added.

Comment: Why did you remove my edits? The question is unreadable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be most commonly done with standard subsetting.

```
df = data.frame(names = c("Paul", "Peter", "Mary", "Eve", "John"), 
                sex = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male"), 
                age = c(15, 20, 12, 14, 10))

df[df$age < 20 & df$age > 12, ]
```

Responding to your edit, if you want to not include missing values, i.e. `NA` you can add: `!is.na()`.

For instance in your example if you want anyone with age above 15 but it can't be NA:

```
df[df$age > 15 & !is.na(df$age), ]
```

Comment: kindly, let me put it this way, In the starwars data set (from library("tidyverse"), how can i view values with mass>100 & mass<200.

Comment: In that case it would be: `starwars[starwars$mass > 100 & starwars$mass < 200 & !is.na(starwars$mass),]` Don't forget to accept my answer if you're happy with it :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked but also include missing values:             starwars[starwars$mass > 100 & starwars$mass < 200,]           how do i remove missing values from that list

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less the same as [ljwharbers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62698473/10442423), but uses the `with` function to reduce the amount of times you need to call the `df`

```
df[with(df, age > 12 & age < 20 & !is.na(age) ),]

  names    sex age
1  Paul   Male  15
4   Eve Female  14
```

If you want to remove all the rows that contain any `NA`'s you can also use this

```
df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
```

Comment: Also a great solution. Another possibility would be to use data.table resulting in just the following `df[age > 12 & age < 20 & !is.na(age),]`. After you've set the dataframe to a datatable with `setDT(df)` of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter` function from dplyr package.

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(names = c("Paul", "Peter", "Mary", "Eve", "John"), 
                sex = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male"), 
                age = c(15, 20, 12, 14, 10))
df %>% filter(age > 12 & age < 20)

#   names sex    age
#1  Paul  Male   15
#2  Eve   Female 14
```